# sauerkraut with toasted sesame seeds

Tags: lactofermentation

I tried making some sauerkraut with red cabbage, carrots, ginger, and toasted sesame seeds. I used a fermentation crock that maintained its seal. After about four weeks it had a cheesy, yeasty smell to it and there was almost no liquid left. There was no mold and no visible kahm yeast. Could this have been caused by the sesame seeds going rancid? Or did this happen because it lost so much liquid and the vegetables were exposed to the air in the cock?

Comment: The vegetables being exposed to air is the most likely culprit, but were the sesame seeds rancid?  Sesame seeds can also get moldy, which seems more likely to cause bacterial odors than their oil becoming rancid (which typically results in a bitter taste or a “chemical” smell)

Comment: The sesame seeds are not rancid.